# How to view question edit history when my question is migrated to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, migration, revisions-list

How view the question edit history when my question is migrated to another Stack Exchange site?
For example, this question: [Make Startpage search results page bold or highlight keywords used](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122427)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click on the superuser.com link underneath the question:

[image]

It will take you to [this page](https://superuser.com/posts/1377543/revisions) with the original question's revision history:

[image]